# Automapper - Map list of objects to single complex type with nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am using an Automapper and I need to map a list of objects to a single complex type, which has a lot of nested objects, but I can't find what may be the right way to do that. Of course I have a lot more concrete objects, but I'm just simplifying my situation.

**Source:**

```
public abstract class SourceBase 
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Source1 : SourceBase
{
}

public class Source2 : SourceBase
{
}
```

**Destination:**

```
public abstract class DestBase 
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Dest1 : DestBase
{
}

public class Dest2 : DestBase
{
}
```

I have this response from the service:

```
public List<SourceBase> Foo { get; set; }
```

And I want to map it into this object:

```
public class DestObj 
{
    public Dest1 Dest1Obj { get; set; }
    public Dest2 Dest2Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why though? You get a list of `SourceBase`? Why not map it to a list of `DestBase`?

Comment: Because we want to make it simpler for frontend view models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I've written a custom mapper with Linq.

```
CreateMap<List<SourceBase>, DestObj>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Dest1Obj, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Single(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Source1))))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Dest2Obj, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Single(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Source2))));

CreateMap<Source1, Dest1>();
CreateMap<Source2, Dest2>();
```